# Drawing a weighted tree using MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I'm new at Java. I'm trying to use GUI to input and display a weighted binary tree. To create root node, user clicks on screen. Subsequently, he drags from one point to another to create an edge and a new node. Once he releases the mouse, he should be prompted to enter the weight, and then edge (with weight displayed) and new node should be displayed.

In the input, while I'm able to create the root, when I try to drag to create the next node, the program goes into a loop.

Code is given below.

```
class myPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
int node_is_present[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //1 if node exists, 0     otherwise
int no_of_nodes=0;
int node_coords[][]=new int[15][2]; //stores co-ordinates of each node
int weight[]=new int[15]; //stores weight of line in the order entered
int x1,x2,y1,y2;
int tracker=-1;
int SIZE=20;

public void clear()
{
    x1=0;
    y1=0;
    x2=0;
    y2=0;
}

 @Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) //will store intial x,y
{
        tracker=1;
        x1=me.getX();
        y1=me.getY();
        repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) //will store final x,y and update arrays
{

    x2=me.getX();
    y2=me.getY();
    if(x1!=x2)
    tracker=2;

    node_is_present[no_of_nodes]=1;
    node_coords[no_of_nodes][0]=me.getX();
    node_coords[no_of_nodes][1]=me.getY();
    no_of_nodes++;
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {}        


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if(tracker==1 && no_of_nodes==0) //for root node
    {
        g.drawOval(x1-(SIZE/2),y1-(SIZE/2),SIZE,SIZE);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(no_of_nodes+1),x1-(SIZE/2),y1-(SIZE/2));
    }

    else if(tracker==2 && no_of_nodes>0)
    {
        g.drawLine(x1 -(SIZE/2) , y1 -(SIZE/2) , x2 -(SIZE/2) , y2 -(SIZE/2));
        g.drawOval(x2-(SIZE/2),y2-(SIZE/2),SIZE,SIZE);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(no_of_nodes+1),x2-(SIZE/2),y2-(SIZE/2));

        String str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the weight of the edge: ");
        int w=Integer.parseInt(str);
        weight[no_of_nodes-1]=w;

        g.drawString(String.valueOf(w),Math.round((x1+x2)/2),Math.round((y1+y2)/2));
        clear();

    }
}

myPanel()
{
    this.setSize(1500, 500);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    clear();
}
}


public class tree1
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    myPanel panel=new myPanel();
    frame.setSize(1500, 800);
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);
    frame.setTitle("Tree");
    frame.setBounds(100,100,1500,800);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: What are the `$` for? Also your `paintComponent(...)` method appears to have program logic in it -- `clear()`. This should not be. consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem. Also, remember to break this big problem into small ones, solving each smaller simpler problem in isolation of the others before trying to combine everything.

Comment: $ - formatting issue, fixed it. The clear() isn't a part of paintcomponent - it's a separate function defined above that resets values of all co-ords to 0.

Comment: I know that, but you're calling it from *within* paintComponent. Again, don't do that as you do not have full control over whether or even if paintComponent gets called.

Comment: The concerns the hovercraftfullofeels has is that fact that you don't control the paint process, painting may occur for any number of reasons, many which you don't control.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting in Swing may occur at any time for any reason.  As @HoverCraftFullOfEels has already pointed out, you should have NO application within any paint method, these should contain ONLY the functionality required to paint your component.

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about the paint sub system

Basically, within your `paintComponent`, call `super.paintComponent` first and remove, in particular, the `else` block.

Make yourself some kind of model, which holds the required data and then use the `paintComponent` method to paint that model.